# Execute mysql query multiple times based on the number of values in a PHP variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table for capturing transactions. I am trying to display data in multiple php/html tables based on the available categories in the same table. sample data from my table is given below.

```
Date       Category     Particulars      type        Amount 
-----------------------------------------------------------
01.12.17   Donation     Received from X  Receipt     500.00
10.12.17   Donation     Received from Y  Receipt     200.00  
15.12.17   Medical Aid  Paid to A        Payment     100.00
20.12.17   Expense      Building Rent    Payment      50.00
```

Is it possible to execute by below query multiple times dynamically based on the distinct value available in category field. This is to populate query data in multiple tables in a single PHP page.

```
select * from my_table where category = 'Donation';
select * from my_table where category = 'Medical Aid';
...
...
```

and the expected result is like below...

```
Date       Category     Particulars      type        Amount 
-----------------------------------------------------------
01.12.17   Donation     Received from X  Receipt     500.00
10.12.17   Donation     Received from Y  Receipt     200.00
-----------------------------------------------------------

-----------------------------------------------------------
Date       Category     Particulars      type        Amount 
-----------------------------------------------------------
15.12.17   Medical Aid  Paid to A        Payment     100.00
-----------------------------------------------------------

-----------------------------------------------------------
Date       Category     Particulars      type        Amount 
-----------------------------------------------------------
20.12.17   Expense      Building Rent    Payment      50.00
```

The values in the category table my change. I trying to display the output of the first query in a separate html table and the second one on another.

Comment: why not use one query and OR?????????

Comment: yes , first you get the category value and store in one variable and than create dynamic query in loop .

Answer (score 2):

You should generally strive to issue the fewest number of queries possible, since this will minimize the number of network calls and overhead in your PHP application.  I would recommend just using a single query with an `ORDER BY` clause on the `category`:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE category IN ('Donation', 'Medical Aid', ...)
ORDER BY category;
```

When you iterate the result set in PHP, the records for each category will be grouped together, and you can create a new HTML table for each category.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table ...";    // your query goes here
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$category = NULL;

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($category != $row['category']) {
            if ($category != NULL) {
                echo '</table>';
            }
            echo '<table>';
            $category = $row['category'];
        }

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['date'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['category'] . '</td>';
        // and other columns in the table
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';    // close the final table
}
```

The above script is just intended to point you in the right direction.  The HTML you actually want might be more complex than this.

Answer (score 0):

I just Ran a Query for each catigory then output in its own table.

```
$getCategories = "select category from my_table";
$catResults = $mysqli->query($catResults);
if ($catResults->num_rows > 0){
foreach ($catResults as $catRes){ 
$myQuery= "select * from my_table where category = '".$catRes."'";
$myResults = $mysqli->query($myResults);
if ($myResults->num_rows > 0){
while($row = $myResults->fetch_assoc()){  
$myResults = $row['date'];
$myResults = $row['Donation'];
$myResults = $row['particulars'];
$myResults = $row['type'];
$myResults = $row['amount'];
echo "<table style=\"width:100%\">"
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>".$catRes."</th>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$row['time']."</td>";    
echo "<td>".$row['Donation']."</td>";  
echo "<td>".$row['particulars']."</td>";     
echo "<td>".$row['type']."</td>";   
echo "<td>".$row['amount']."</td>"; 
echo "</tr>"; }}}}
```

Comment: what will do in case i dont know how many number of categories available in the field.

Answer (score -1):

First Get All Category List

```
select Category from my_table
```

Store it in array.Than Use [Foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) Statement to execute All Query.